# How to detect WebKit Inspector?

Tags: detect, web-inspector

I know how to detect Firebug in FF (if (window.console && window.console.firebug) alert ('Buu'); ) but how detect or disable Web Inspector in WebKit??

Comment: Just FYI, Chrome (built on Webkit) has Web Inspector built in, so it will always be in the browser - make sure you don't inconvenience your users because of it, thay may not even know about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend trying to reach out of your website and into the user's browser settings. If you succeed in turning off Web Inspector, users will start wondering why Web Inspector is spontaneously dying.

Answer (score 0):

The Web Inspector injected code runs in an isolated world inside the inspected page for Chrome, so it cannot be detected from the code running in the inspected page's main world (see e.g. a class comment in http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-777.1/bindings/v8/V8IsolatedContext.h).